# Focusing text-input dims surrounding text labels

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome, input, colors

Can't find anything on the topic, no idea if this is something old or new.

Basically, given an `input[text]` with adjacent `div` for a label which has any color besides pure black/white -- when selected (and caret is flickering inside) input somehow affects surrounding elements and visually dims them. Like some kind of filter is applied? Like a shadow or a blur or something, but it **affects the entire parent' render stack** no matter how far elements are from the input distance wise. TLDR: everything visually below the input is affected.

I tried checking computed props on labels and found nothing. CSSOM does not changes for them in any way.

You can try [codepen](https://codepen.io/MrNovado/pen/YzvLyNv), or any other sandbox.

The code is very simple:

```html
<html style="color: #ffffff; background-color: #1e1e1e">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
      <div style="color: #f54562">Error 1</div>
      <div style="color: #f54562">Error 2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>;
```

I made a gif here:

[image]

Moving `input` into an absolute position helps isolating the effect, but obviously working with inputs like that would be very tiresome.

Checked on 2 different machines.

- Reproducible in Chrome: Version `107.0.5304.107` (Official Build) (64-bit);
- Edge also;
- Works fine in Firefox;

So, some kind of bug or known quirk?

Comment: Seem like a blink/windows specific issue at the moment; sent a report via chrome, lets see what happens.

Comment: Reported the issue here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1394698

Comment: UPD: Merged into the issue here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1353921